# Fly.io django and postgres deploy

Tags: django, postgresql, deployment, utf-8, fly

I'm trying to deploy my django app in Fly.io with postgreSQL database, so I've followed de docs to attach my app with the postgres cluster with the main app.

I’ve generated the DATABASE_URL like this:

```
flyctl pg attach ac7-postgres
```

> ```
> Checking for existing attachments
> Registering attachment
> Creating database
> Creating user
>
> Postgres cluster ac7-postgres is now attached to ac7
> The following secret was added to ac7:
> DATABASE_URL=postgres://ac7:<'PASSWORD'>@ac7-postgres.flycast:5432/ac7?sslmode=disable
> ```

So I have this code in settings.py:

```
os.environ['DATABASE_URL'] = 'postgres://ac7:<PASSWORD>@ac7-postgres.flycast:5432/ac7?sslmode=disable'

DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(default=os.getenv('DATABASE_URL'))
}
```

but when I try “`py manage.py makemigrations`” it shows:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: ‘utf-8’ codec can’t decode byte 0xe3 in position 76: invalid continuation byte
```

Can someone help me? Please

Comment: Is the schema of your url correct? Reading the docs of `dj-database-url` you might have an incorrect token in your url. That's the only possible way for this error to be raised and I suspect it might have to do with `<` and `>`

Comment: I'm reading the docs, but my password has no special characters to encode, and I've tried using <> too but it raises the same error

Comment: Have you tried running you configuration without `dj-database-url`? I downloaded the source code for the library and it only just returns a config dictionnary and didn't raise any errors with the url you provided `{'NAME': 'ac7', 'USER': 'ac7', 'PASSWORD': '<PASSWORD>', 'HOST': 'ac7-postgres.flycast', 'PORT': 5432, 'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0, 'CONN_HEALTH_CHECKS': False, 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql', 'OPTIONS': {'sslmode': 'disable'}}` so thinking about it, it might have to do with something related to one of the config parameters. Have you also correctly interpolated `<PASSWORD>`?

Comment: Also are you sure that the value returned from `os.getenv` is a string and not `None`? (Just in case)

Comment: DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'ac7', 
        'USER': 'ac7',
        'PASSWORD': '<PASSWORD>',
        'HOST': 'ac7-postgres.flycast',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'sslmode': 'disable',
        }
    }
}

this shows the exact same error

Comment: and yep, that code is returning a string